# BLYNK_TEMPLATE_ID and BLYNK_TEMPLATE_NAME error in Arduino ide compiler

Tags: iot, blynk

i have mentioned both the BLYNK_TEMPLATE_ID and BLYNK_TEMPLATE_NAME but i am still getting this error.
i have tried everything so far till now but it is not working. i have given the code below so you guys ca have a look at it i am following a Youtube video for my project, in video he didn't got any error but when i tried the same code just added info about blynk template that i created i even have installed all the needed libraries.
I want to link my BLYNK application with my IOT project to control it from my phone using blynk platform. i am stuck at this error from last two days.
this is the error i a encountering #error "Please specify your BLYNK_TEMPLATE_ID and BLYNK_TEMPLATE_NAME"

here is the code

````
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp32.h>
#define sensor 33
#define relay 4
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);
#define BLYNK_TEMPLATE_ID "TMPL6emdmuXgp"
#define BLYNK_TEMPLATE_NAME "Plant watering System"
#define BLYNK_AUTH_TOKEN "***************************"
BlynkTimer timer;

char auth[] = "****************************";
char ssid[] = "Duaaa";
char pass[] = "*********";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass, "blynk.cloud", 80);
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  pinMode(relay, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
.
.
.
.
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version of Blynk library may require these lines of code

```
#define BLYNK_TEMPLATE_ID "TMPL6emdmuXgp"
#define BLYNK_TEMPLATE_NAME "Plant watering System"
#define BLYNK_AUTH_TOKEN "***************************"
```

at the very top of your sketch.

Try adding these in the top most part of your code :)

Earlier versions of the Blynk library used `BLYNK_DEVICE_NAME` rather than `BLYNK_TEMPLATE_NAME`.

If you're still stuck and using an old format, try using `BLYNK_DEVICE_NAME` instead of `BLYNK_TEMPLATE_NAME`